# AJAX call fails in phonegap app

Tags: cordova

I have an error like "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.localhost:56891' is therefore not allowed access." and my code look like this:

```
 $.ajax({
 url: 'http://192.168.4.12:90/api/gps',
 type: "GET",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) {
 alert("success");
 },
 error: function (xhr, type) {
 alert("Error connecting to the servers");
 }
 }, 'json');
```

I have a WebApi project on localhost and i put in IIS, and it returns my json ok if i put the link in a web browser,but in the phonegap project always falls. I put 
`<access origin="*"/>`  in config.xml, but is the same error.
If someone can help me please, because i'm looking for two weeks for an solution and nothing works.

Comment: Where you test ajax, on browser or device. If on browser then if always error. You should research about CORS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'jsonp' instead of 'json' for the data type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i don't have that error, but always it calls the error function.

Comment: I tryed again with json and in all the browsers its working, but in chrome emulator not.

Comment: @Dawson Other options than jsonp ? I am facing the same issue. Xhr status comes as 0 and responseText as empty string, any links?